# Finding the XPath for a few rows in a Table?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xpath, hpple

I'm currently attempting to pull in specific data from an html site using xpath queries, but I'm having trouble pulling in specific parts.

Using `//div[@id='main']/h2` as my xpath query I am able to pull the "View Current" text using the following:

```
exampleSite.title = [[element firstChild] content];
```

However I would also like to pull in the following:

```
1. <b>5/9/2013<nbsp><nbsp> 10:58:45 PM</b>
2. <b>6.32</b>
3. <b>5  Total Points</b>
4. <b>3.72</b>
```

**So far I've got this: `//div[@id='main']/table[@class='bodytext']/tr` but that's where I get stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!**

Here is the html I'm attempting to scrape:

```
<div id="main">
<h2>View Current</h2>

      <table width="96%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#eeeeee" align="center" height="276" valign="top" class="bodytext">
        <tr valign="top" >
          <td colspan = 2 height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="54%" class="headerblue" >Balances <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" > 
          <td colspan = 2 height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="54%" class="text" >Balances 
            as of: <b>5/9/2013<nbsp><nbsp> 10:58:45 PM</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" > 
          <td colspan = 2 height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="46%" class="text" >Account 
            Number: <b>101010123</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" > 
          <td colspan = 2 height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="46%" class="text" ></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top" > 
          <td height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="46%" class="text" >Example Card Amount: 
            <b>6.32</b></td>
<td height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="46%" class="text" ><a href="balance.asp?">View Details</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top" > 
          <td height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="46%" class="text" >Example Dining Plans:<b>5  Total Points</b>

</td>
<td height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="46%" class="text" ><a href="balance2.asp?">View Details</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top" > 
          <td height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="46%" class="text" >Credit For Printing: 
            <b>3.72</b></td>
<td height="13" valign="top" align="left" width="46%" class="text" ><a href="balance1.asp?">View Details</a></td>
        </tr>

          <td colspan = 2 height="13" valign="top" align="CENTER"  class="text">For 
            questions contact Cashiers at<BR> (000)000-0011 or <a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top"> 
          <td colspan = 2 height="13" valign="top" align="CENTER"  class="text" > 

<a href="balance1.asp">All Plan Usage for last 90 days is available here</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top"> 
          <td colspan = 2 height="13" valign="top" align="CENTER"  class="text" > 

<a href="balance.asp?pln=Full">All Usage for last 365 days is available here</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

      </table>



</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//div[@id='main']/table[@class='bodytext']/tr/td/b` should give you a list of all `<b>`s in your table cells.

Comment: Thanks Mennny. Assuming I have different labels. How would I be able to specifcially assign each <b> text to each label? Say I want Label 1 to have the 3rd <b> and label 2 to have the 1st <b>, etc.

Comment: Do you mean mapping the content of the `<b>`s to a specific `title` attribute in your Objective-C? I think for a dynamic HTML structure you have to match it using the content of the enclosing `<td>` tag. If your HTML is static, you can write a static `NSDictionary` mapping the indices to the `title`s. EDIT: Which class do you use for parsing the HTML?

Comment: I'm using Hpple. Also, the actual text in each <b> changes if a user uses their card / account.

Comment: @user1886754: I tried to answer your questions in my answer. Let me know if you have questions!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension to Mennny's answer, which is actually right, so you should accept it.
I'll try to answer your additional questions in the comments:

You do your parsing like this: (`htmlData` is my demo data)

```
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[@"/Users/dennis/Desktop/demo.html" stringByStandardizingPath]];
TFHpple *parser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *bTags = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@id='main']/table[@class='bodytext']/tr/td/b"];
```

After that you put the contents of the parsed `<b>`tags in an `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *stringsInBTag = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (TFHppleElement *element in bTags) {
    [stringsInBTag addObject:element.content];
}
```

What you get there is: (logged output of the array)

> (
>       "5/9/2013",
>       101010123,
>       "6.32",
>       "5  Total Points",
>       "3.72"
>   )

Now you want to set your labels:

```
// Set label 1 to third <b>
self.label1.text = stringsInBTag[2];

// Set label 2 to first <b> 
self.label2.text = stringsInBTag[0];
```

Comment: Thank you HAS! This looks really good! However, I'm getting a thread 1 error :/ Just so that I don't clog up this question, I've opened it up here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481907/assigning-specific-b-tags-to-uilabels with more details regarding the example you provided. Thanks for the help!